# SQL - Compare Data from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the below table with following columns -

ID-1, ID-2 and ID-3 - Key columns

Rate - Shows the rate of a product based on the above IDs

Date - implied the date for which that Rate applies.

```
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| ID-1  | ID-2     | ID-3        | Rate     |   Date     |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 2000  | 1        | 100         | 50       | 12/30/2013 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 2000  | 1        | 100         | 75       | 10/11/2013 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 2000  | 1        | 100         | 100      | 12/15/2013 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 2000  | 2        | 100         | 50       | 10/30/2013 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 2000  | 2        | 100         | 75       | 10/11/2013 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 2000  | 2        | 100         | 100      | 09/15/2013 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 3000  | 2        | 200         | 25       | 1/1/2014   |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 4000  | 2        | 100         | 100      | 12/1/2013  |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 4000  | 1        | 200         | 75       | 1/1/2014   |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 4000  | 2        | 100         | 25       | 11/1/2014  |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

For each combination of ID-1, ID-2 and ID-3 I want to ouput 2 recent most rates in the following format -
Previous Rate - is the rate for the second most recent date
Current Rate - is the rate for the recent most date

```
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| ID-1  | ID-2     | ID-3        | Previous Rate |  Current Rate  |
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 2000  | 1        | 100         | 100           | 50             |
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 2000  | 2        | 100         | 75            | 50             |
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 3000  | 2        | 200         |               | 25             |
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 4000  | 1        | 200         |               | 75             |
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
| 4000  | 2        | 200         | 25            | 100            |
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2833/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( "ID-1", "ID-2", "ID-3", Rate, "Date" ) AS
          SELECT 2000  , 1        , 100         , 50       , TO_DATE( '12/30/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2000  , 1        , 100         , 75       , TO_DATE( '10/11/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2000  , 1        , 100         , 100      , TO_DATE( '12/15/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2000  , 2        , 100         , 50       , TO_DATE( '10/30/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2000  , 2        , 100         , 75       , TO_DATE( '10/11/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2000  , 2        , 100         , 100      , TO_DATE( '09/15/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3000  , 2        , 200         , 25       , TO_DATE( '1/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4000  , 2        , 100         , 100      , TO_DATE( '12/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4000  , 1        , 200         , 75       , TO_DATE( '1/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4000  , 2        , 100         , 25       , TO_DATE( '11/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH rankings AS (
  SELECT "ID-1",
         "ID-2",
         "ID-3",
         Rate,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "ID-1", "ID-2", "ID-3"
                            ORDER BY "Date" DESC, Rate DESC ) AS "Rank"
  FROM   test
)
SELECT "ID-1",
       "ID-2",
       "ID-3",
       MAX( CASE "Rank" WHEN 1 THEN Rate END ) AS current_rate,
       MAX( CASE "Rank" WHEN 2 THEN Rate END ) AS previous_rate
FROM   rankings
GROUP BY
       "ID-1",
       "ID-2",
       "ID-3"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2833/5/0)**:

```
| ID-1 | ID-2 | ID-3 | CURRENT_RATE | PREVIOUS_RATE |
|------|------|------|--------------|---------------|
| 2000 |    1 |  100 |           50 |           100 |
| 2000 |    2 |  100 |           50 |            75 |
| 3000 |    2 |  200 |           25 |        (null) |
| 4000 |    1 |  200 |           75 |        (null) |
| 4000 |    2 |  100 |           25 |           100 |
```

Comment: MT0 - why are we doing a max() in the select?

Comment: The `rankings` sub-query will assign each row within an `ID-1`, `ID-2` & `ID-3` partition an Olympic rank based on descending date-rate order; however, this does not group the rows in the partition. In order to ensure a single value is returned you need to group the rows and this requires an aggregation function - i.e. `MAX`); because of the previous ordering of the rows to assign the rank then 'MIN' or 'AVG' would have worked just as well but I arbitrarily picked 'MAX'.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
select
  id-1,
  id-2,
  id-3,
  first_value(rate) over (partition by id-1, id-2, id-3 order by date desc) as current_rate
  lead(rate,1) over (partition by id-1, id-2, id-3 order by date desc) as prev_rate
from
  table
```

Comment: The above query is bringing back duplicate rows, but with correct current and previous values from all rows available with respect to the Date. Lead function is just comparing the data from the current row with the next row and returning data. Observe that for ID-1 = 2000, I have 6 rows altogether but output only contains 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
SELECT id1, id2, id3, prev_rate, curr_rate
FROM(
     SELECT id1, 
            id2, 
            id3,
            rate AS curr_rate, 
            LEAD(rate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2, id3 ORDER BY date DESC) AS prev_rate,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2, id3 ORDER BY date DESC) AS rnk
     FROM   <table_name>
     )
WHERE rnk = 1;
```